# CALayer rendering issues with diagonal dashed line

Tags: ios, core-graphics, calayer

I've created a dashed `CAShapeLayer` using the code below. The line draws correctly when its path is on a perfectly horizontal plane. However as soon as the path moves up or down, the line suffers from some issues. See the images as an example.

```
CGMutablePathRef linePath = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathMoveToPoint(linePath, NULL, startShapeLayer.centerX, startShapeLayer.centerY);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(linePath, NULL, endShapeCenter.x, endShapeCenter.y);
CGPathCloseSubpath(linePath);

CAShapeLayer *lineLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
lineLayer.path = linePath;
lineLayer.fillColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
lineLayer.strokeColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
lineLayer.lineCap = kCALineCapRound;
lineLayer.lineDashPattern = @[@5, @5];
lineLayer.lineDashPhase = 5.0;
lineLayer.lineWidth = 1.0;
```

If anyone has some advice about drawing these kinds of shapes it'd be great to hear.

[image: Correct]

[image: Incorrect]

Comment: Is there a particular purpose for using a shape layer for this as opposed to a UIBezierPath?

Comment: Ultimately I want to animate the drawing of the line (from start to end), which is why I went with a CAShapeLayer.

Comment: Try taking out the line, CGPathCloseSubpath(linePath); Does that give you what you want?

Comment: Thanks so much, that enables the line to draw as it should in all directions. You've also inadvertently fixed this issue I was having also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24624379/trouble-timing-two-cabasicanimations-together/24654299#24654299. I guess the closing of the subpath was extending the length of line to be drawn. I thought closing a path was required.